# Dojox legend color for markers incorrect

Tags: charts, dojo

I have a dojox chart where the legend created for the chart never
has the correct color for markers.  The legend color for the marker
should match what's on the chart.  It's always seems to use a default
color to represent the marker in the legend.  Any ideas?? Possible bug??

BTW:  I'm using Dojo 1.3.0

Thx!!

John

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you are doing please?  The test seems to look ok.  http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_chart2d_dynamics.html  Still might be a bug though.

Comment: Seth,

Thanks for the reply..See my comment below from Eugene's post...

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance creating the legend before populating a chart? Or do you make other changes to the chart? If you want to reflect any changes in the legend widget, you should call `refresh()` method on it.

In order to eliminate the guess work it would be better to post a minimal example, or point to an existing test/demo.

Comment: Eugene,

Thanks for the reply.  I placed a test page on:

http://www.airtalk.com/dojo/test/index1.html

It's a work-in-progress piece designed to show leak 
locations based on pressure and distance.  After clicking
on the 'Make Graph' button, you can observe the legend
and color difference.  Next, select the 'Show User Input'
checkbox and again observe the legend color.

Thx!!

John

Comment: If I am not mistaken lines colors are correct, but marker colors are wrong. Marker shapes appear correct. Please file a bug (http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/) against DojoX GFX, and reference this test case.

Comment: Yes, line color and marker shapes are correct in the legend. Only the color of the markers in the legend are incorrect. I'll file a bug and reference this test case. Thank you for taking the time to help out

Comment: Excellent! I plan to fix it in the trunk tomorrow. Chances are it will be a drop-in replacement, you can use with 1.3.0.

Comment: Thx again Eugene..I'm really turning into a big fan of everything dojo...Especially the charting..

Comment: The bug is fixed. Use the trunk for now. I modified your code (commented out bad axes parameters) and attached it to the ticket.